# Marshaling from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I gotta pass an InParameter from my C# application to an exported function from a VC++ DLL. The function accepts 2 parameters :

```
int func_name (FILE* fp, BYTE& by);
```

`fp` is In and `by` is Out parameter.

I was thinking of marshaling using `IntPtr` for the `FILE*` and using byte for `BYTE`. Is it correct? If I write the following in C#

```
[DllImport("name_of_project.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] public static extern int      func_name(IntPtr FilePointer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BYTE&)] byte by);
```

will it work? I think it will give an error for the '&' sign in the marshaling statement. How do I pass the out parameter by reference?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,Viren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If native function expects reference, you can marshal it using it ref/out. So in your situation, you could use:
`out byte by`. I've checked it, and it works for me.

**Edit again:** It just came to my mind, that advices I gave you won't work, as FILE is a struct, that you won't be able to marshall from c# that easily. So scratch those, you can use this approach if you will threat SafeFileHandle as HANDLE object inside your unmanaged library. If you can't modify this dll, one solution is to create own wrapper for creating files using stdio, it could look like this:

1. Create library that exposes functionality of fopen, fclose etc. Fe. (in c++):

   ```
   FILE* CreateFile(char* name);
   ```
2. Marhall this function, in this example you would use (c#):

   ```
   public static extern IntPtr CreateMyFile([MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name);
   ```
3. Marshall all FILE* parameters to IntPtr, and then just pass result of function    `CreateMyFile` as FILE*.

Comment: thanks Ravadre. But I am still stuck with FILE * type marshalling. Can you please suggest a statement for the same: should I use the 4 byte unsigned integer? I do not have the code to test right now. I will get it soon and will update here asap.. For now I am thinking of the following: 
DllImport("name_of_project.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int func_name(U4 FilePointer, out byte by);

Comment: Uf, sorry for all those edits, I've checked this solution and it works pretty well.

Comment: One point: make sure that both unmanaged dlls link to the same C++ runtime dll, or to the same version of static C++ runtime library.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't work as written.

1. Where are you going to get a `FILE*` in a C# program? Unless some other function in your unmanaged dll gives you this pointer, you're in trouble. BTW I strongly recommend wrapping this `FILE*` in a [`SafeHandle`](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/08/12/213808.aspx); then your p/invoke signature will use a `SafeFilePointer` instead of a bare `IntPtr`.
2. How many bytes are you marshaling? If just one, put `out byte by` in the managed signature (no attributes required).
3. You don't need to specify a charset, since you are not marshaling any `char`s or `string`s.

Comment: I am Marshaling 1 byte only. So can you please suggest a statement for the FILE* to be Marshalled. I am new to .NET programming and have no idea about wrapping a FILE* with SafeHandle.

Thanks,
Viren

Comment: I'll repeat myself — where are you getting that FILE*? Do you need to open a file, or what?

Comment: I have int func_name(FILE* fp, BYTE& by) exported in the C++ DLL which I am importing in my C# application. In my C# application I inted to open a binary file and pass the Handle to the imported function. I am not sure yet how to get the handle in C#. I assume that we can open a binary file in C# and get its handle just like we do in C++ using File* fp = _tfopen(path, mode).

Comment: You can't do that. The `FILE*` which your unmanaged function wants belongs to the C++ runtime library linked with your unmanaged dll, which isn't necessarily the same as the C++ runtime library linked to CLR. And anyway .NET doesn't use `FILE*` internally, it builds I/O over native `HANDLE`s. Do you have control over the unmanaged dll's source?

Comment: I have access to it but it is a read only access. I am not allowed to modify it and it is not meant to be modified anyways as it is on a live (production) system.

Comment: First of all, see whether your unmanaged dll exports file opening/closing functions. If not, and your unmanaged dll is dynamically linked to C++ runtime library, you can p/invoke `_tfopen` and `fclose` from that. You'll have to [DllImport] the same C++ runtime dll your dll uses. Otherwise you'll be reduced to hacking: essentially you'll have to re-implement `fopen` and `FILE` in managed code. But this is a very evil approach, only to be used as a *last* resort.